# Array Declaration: Double Quotes & Parentheses

Tags: bash, variable, quoting, bash-array

Perhaps this is a stupid question but two hours on Google hasn't turned up anything on point.

Simply, does a difference exist in Bash between:

```
X="
a
b
c
"
```

and

```
X=(
a
b
c
)
```

The former conforms with the definition of a variable, the latter, the definition of an array.

An array is a multi-element variable, so is this to say that the former also is an array for all purposes?

If the former is an array, is the only difference in operation as between (a) the double quotes and (b) the parentheses, the operation of quoting rules on the array's elements?

Many thanks for any insights.

Comment: What you have there is a string and an array of strings. They are very different. An array holds multiple strings, a string holds characters.

Comment: That first one is a string with newlines in it. It's only a cheap approximation of an array if you do something like `words="foo bar doo"; for x in $words; do ...`, which people tend to do since not all shells have proper named arrays (or they don't know how to use them, or feel their syntax is icky). But it's still the equivalent of e.g. Python's `for x in str.split(" ")`, and not `for x in list`. If nothing else, elements containing newlines/spaces would cause issues with that sort of an "array".

Comment: The magic is not in Google, but in: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays

Comment: @Paul_Penant, I regret that you did not apprehend that that was where I started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string of newline-delimited substrings is not the same thing as an array of strings.  One is a string; the other contains strings.

The fact that your string is divided into lines by the inclusion of newline characters in the string has no particular significance to the storage of the string. The shell can not index it on lines, and a single line can't contain an embedded newline character without encoding it somehow.

The array is an ordered set of separate strings.  Each string is immediately accessible via an index into the array. A single array element may contain any standard string, with or without newlines or other delimiting characters (except the nul character in the `bash` shell).  However, an array element can't be another array, as `bash` does not support multi-dimensional arrays.

```bsh
string1='Hello World'

string2="'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
      Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
      And the mome raths outgrabe."

array=( "$string1" "$string2" )

printf '%s\n' "${array[1]}"
```

The above script fragment prints the first verse from the poem Jabberwocky by Lewis Carroll.  It does not print `Hello World` as we choose to output the array's second element, not the first.  The second element is a single string made up of characters.  Some of those characters happen to be newlines and blanks, but this is done only for presentation purposes.

To output only a single line, or any other substring, from the poem in the second array element, we need to use some utility to parse the string.  Extracting individual newline-delimited substrings from a string does not have anything to do with the concept of arrays in the shell.

Comment: So, the word splitting that occurs by reason of whitespace does not mean each word is an array element, notwithstanding that a command will iterate through the words.  And, even though the iteration occurs, the word list (for lack of a better phrase) is not indexed.

Comment: @ebsf Word-splitting occurs on an unquoted string, at the locations characters also present in `$IFS` (space, tab, and newline by default). After word splitting, the generated terms also undergo filename globbing. The result of these operations is highly dependent on the environment (the `$IFS` values as well as certain shell options, like those affecting file name globbing).

Answer (score 5):

No, the former is not an array.

For example, you can't use an index to select a member:

```bsh
arr=(a b c)
echo "${arr[1]}"  # b
```

You can use an array to pass arguments, but you can't use a string. Use elements containing spaces for greater effect:

```bsh
arr=(a 'b c' d)
printf '(%s)\n' "${arr[@]}"

string=$'\nm\nn o\np\n'
printf '(%s)\n' $string
```

Output:

```
(a)
(b c)
(d)
(m)
(n)
(o)
(p)
```

`man bash` contains descriptions of both the variable types, no googling needed.

Comment: For an even clearer effect, you can include newlines in array elements: `arr=(a 'b c' $'d\ne\nf' g)`

Comment: For a scalar variable, you can also use an index to select a member but in ksh/bash, there's only one member, on index 0. `${scalar[0]}` is like `$scalar`, while in zsh/yash, `${scalar[x]}` gives you the `x`th *character* of the scalar.

Comment: The syntax `${scalar[x]}` in zsh/yash is only asserting that an string is also an array. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: But the type of each element in `${scalar[x]}` is not well defined, it may change with a change of locale. This: `zsh -c 'a=áéíóú; echo "${a[2]} ${a:1:1}"'` prints (correctly) `í í`, the second character in the string. But things get out of sync if you add a LC_ALL=C before that command. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Except that man bash and the Bash manual do not, to my reading, reconcile the distinction.  Thanks for the clarification nevertheless.