# Shell bash construction with double quotes and words/items like a list

Tags: bash, shell-script

I met this example in a bash tutorial:

```bash
words="foo bar doo"; for x in $words; do ...
```

My understanding is that in this case `words` is a regular variable defined using `strings and white-spaces. The author does not explain it (it is a beginner bash tutorial).

My question is, what is the feature of bash (or possibly other shells) that makes this work:

```bash
for x in $words
```

-I mean by this that `x` is assigned at each iteration the value `foo`, `bar` and `doo`? Where to find this feature documented in the bash manual? Some links (docs, blog) would be appreciated.

How is this called in bash terminology this construction

```bash
words="foo bar doo"
```

Is it a list (like in Python)?

I found a similar post here [Array Declaration: Double Quotes & Parentheses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/672182/442084) .

Thank you.

Comment: The assignment to `words` is a plain assignment of some text: the spaces have no significance at this point. The unquoted `$words` is explained in the online Bash Reference manual at `3.5.7: Word Splitting`. `for .. in ..` with a word list iterates over its arguments.

Comment: The `for` command is shown in the same manual under `3.2.5.1 Looping Constructs`. See `www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html`

Comment: Thank you all for the references and explanation. Much clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

In the `bash` manual you can see the following:

> ### Word Splitting
>
> **The shell scans the results of parameter expansion**, command
> substitution, and arithmetic expansion **that did not occur within
> double quotes for word splitting**. The shell treats each character of
> `IFS` as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions
> into words on these characters. **If `IFS` is unset, or its value is
> exactly `<space><tab><newline>`**, the default, then sequences of
> `<space>`, , and `<newline>` at the beginning and end of the
> results of the previous expansions are ignored, and **any sequence of
> `IFS` characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words**.
> If `IFS` has a value other than the default, then sequences of the
> whitespace characters space and tab are ignored at the beginning and
> end of the word, as long as the whitespace character is in the value
> of `IFS` (an `IFS` whitespace character). Any character in `IFS` that
> is not `IFS` whitespace, along with any adjacent `IFS` whitespace
> characters, delimits a field. A sequence of `IFS` whitespace
> characters is also treated as a delimiter. If the value of `IFS` is
> null, no word splitting occurs.

The assignment to `words` just creates a string that includes spaces. The question is how you use it.

In your case,

```
words="foo bar doo"; for x in $words; do ...
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for x in foo bar doo; do ...
```

So the shell would split `foo`, `bar` and `doo` to three words (since they're delimited by spaces), and the `for` loop would run three times once for each word, with `$x` being assign with the relevant word each time (like in `python`). Example:

```
$ words="foo bar doo"; for x in $words; do echo $x; done
foo
bar
doo
```

If you would have quoted the `$words` in the `for` loop, it would treat it as a single word that includes spaces and won't split them. So:

```
words="foo bar doo"; for x in "$words"; do ...
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for x in "foo bar doo"; do ...
```

In which case, the loop would only run once, where the value of `$x` would be the `"foo bar doo"` string.

```
$ words="foo bar doo"; for x in "$words"; do echo $x; done
foo bar doo
```